# How do I reorder scopes on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I accidentally unfavourited the Today scope and some others whilst exploring the UI of my Aquaris E4.

I found how to add them back but not how to reorder them? I want the Today scope to be first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pull from the bottom of the screen to get the screen to manage those. Hold your finger on an item to enter the mode where you can re-order, then drag&drop from the icons on the right

Answer (score 4):

In the Manage scopes view (bottom edge of the Dash), a long press on favourited scopes will switch the list to re-ordering mode.